# How can I subscribe to a MQTT topic in a Amazon AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am using python, I am able to publish a message to AWS IoT using the code below:

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='us-east-1')

# Change topic, qos and payload
response = client.publish(
        topic='$aws/things/pi/shadow/update',
        qos=1,
        payload=json.dumps({"foo":"bar"})
    )
```

but there is no method like

> client.subscribe();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to subscribe to all the topics than you don't have to do anything else just go to the iot rule section and invoke your lambda function and print your json string something like this:

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
   print(event)
```

Comment: And you can restrict the topic in the SELECT statement in the AWS IoT rule, as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg5ZDe6xfJY

Answer (score -3):

Because it's working as configurations. Look at documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-lambda-rule.html